# Wordpress - wpdb query does not list same result as sql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a very weird issue with wpdb which is freaking me out. My database has the following data:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_clb_likes` (`id`, `post_id`, `user_ip`, `time`)
VALUES
    (5,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:23:26'),
    (6,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:23:34'),
    (7,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:24:07'),
    (8,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:24:44'),
    (9,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:28:53'),
    (10,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:29:23'),
    (11,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:31:06'),
    (12,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 09:31:30'),
    (13,11172,'::1','2015-01-25 09:43:10'),
    (14,11511,'::1','2015-01-25 20:23:31'),
    (15,11315,'::1','2015-01-25 20:32:01'),
    (16,11025,'::1','2015-01-25 20:32:59');
```

In WP I have the query:

```
        public static function getAllObjects() {
            global $wpdb;
            global $clb_table;
        $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as likes, post_id from $clb_table GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY likes DESC", OBJECT_K);
    return $sql;
}
```

My var_dump on the WP fronted shows this:

```
array(2) { [9]=> object(stdClass)#4818 (2) { ["likes"]=> string(1) "9" ["post_id"]=> string(5) "11511" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#4817 (2) { ["likes"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_id"]=> string(5) "11172" } }
```

Why I am only seeing post_id 11511 and 11172 and not 11315 and 11025 as well?

Does anybody know the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Solved it myself. Because of the OBJECT_K setting in the get_results() the function does not list all items of the database...I replaced OBJECT_K with the default OBJECT and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself. Because of the OBJECT_K setting in the get_results() the function does not list all items of the database...I replaced OBJECT_K with the default OBJECT and it works.